# cryptic clue - palidromic medic with difficult personality loses title [7]

Tags: cryptic-clues

Cryptic crossword type clue

> Palindromic medic with difficult personality loses title [7]

(hints will be provided over time if necessary... )

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think this is

> Dr. Awkward (a "palindromic medic") without Dr (title), making **AWKWARD** ("with a difficult personality")? Although that would have the definition part in the middle, which is contrary to the normal rules of cryptic clues.

Comment: the only issue I have with your answer is the . after the title, but that may be a matter of different conventions... well done -- hmm see the issue that you point out with the normal rules of cryptic clues... wonder if you have any suggestions to improve the clue...

Comment: Maybe a better clueing of this answer would be: “Unfortunate! Palindromic medic loses title [7]”

Comment: Or putting "title stripped from" (or similar) in the beginning of the clue?

Comment: @El-Guest thanks for the suggestion

Comment: @Jafe - how about 

**Palindromic medic with difficult personality finishes rounds [4]**

that seems to get around the problem of there being part of the clue that is too direct.